# Is it possible to have $x^Tyx^TAx=x^T(yx^T)^TAx$? where $x,y$ are vectors of equal dimensions and $A$ is a matrix

Tags: matrices, vectors

Can one write, $x^Tyx^TAx=x^T(yx^T)^TAx$? where $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ or in other words, is it possible to write: $x^TBAx=x^TB^TAx$? where $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$?

Comment: "Is it possible to have...." Sure, just let $A$ be the zero matrix (or $x$ or $y$ the zero vector, or $Ax$ the zero vector...). "Is it possible to write ...." Now I think you're asking whether it's true for *all* $x,y,A$. Have you tried looking for a counterexample? What happens if, say, $x=(1,2)$, $y=(3,4)$, $A=\pmatrix{5&6\cr7&8\cr}$?

Comment: The counterexample I tried, failed unfortunately. I dont think I can generalize this.

Comment: Failed to be a counterexample? or failed to give equality? What happened when you tried my suggested possible counterexample?

Comment: Are you still here, Amardeep?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, 
I cooked up a random example in matlab and the equality failed spectacularly, so I dont think this equality holds. I was trying to prove a theorem in control theory using  this identity. But it seems I will have to abandon my effort in this direction.

Comment: Let me encourage you, Amardeep, to write that up and post it as an answer.

Comment: Hi Gerry! Thanks but how can I uptick your answer?

Comment: I haven't posted an answer, only some comments. There may be some minimum number of points you need to have to uptick a comment. Don't worry about it.